# Pass $(this) to callback of each() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, this, each

I have a function that I call by calling each() on an element in jQuery. I  want to pass the element that I called each() on as an argument. This is an abstracted version of the code that I have now, but when I pass $(this) to the callback of each(), it passes the document instead.

```
var myFunction = function(element){
    //do stuff with element
};

$('.element').each(myFunction($(this)));
```

I'd be happy for any help, cheers!

Comment: Use anonymous function `$('.element').each(function() { myFunction($(this)); });`

Comment: This calls `myFunction` **once** and passes the return value to `.each`, which is `undefined`.

Comment: Use `bind`. `$('.element').each(myFunction.bind($(this)));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.element').each(function(){
    myFunction($(this)); 
});
```

Comment: Don't see a reason for the first line.

Comment: @FelixKling just for the clarity for OP.

Comment: @FelixKling I removed it, was looking confusing. :)

Comment: I don't want to use an anonymous function because I want to call the function in different contexts to stay DRY ;)

EDIT: Sorry, misread your answer, cheers, for the suggestion!

Comment: @cursedphil Can't you just pass a reference to `myFunction`? In doing so, `this` will be bound to the element - http://jsfiddle.net/2b4jsvLh/

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you're working on is something that can be directly converted to a jQuery add-on:

```
$.fn.myFunction = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    // original "myFunction" code
    // here, "this" will be bound to each element
  });
};
```

Now you can write

```
$(".element").myFunction();
```

If you write it with that `return` statement as in my example, you can use it just like any other jQuery function:

```
$(".element").addClass("something-else").myFunction().hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to keep each() out of the function because I want to be able to calling it without each()!

Comment: @cursedphil OK, but that's the general pattern for jQuery - it's why you can write `$(".foo").hide()` to hide all the "foo" elements.  There's an implicit `each()` loop in all those methods.